# iOS - Parse - Updating other PFUsers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have a column called **friends** on my Parse _User table that is a relation.  This relation contains other users that are friends of a particular user.  However, in order for Bob to be a friend of Jane, for example, Jane also has to have Bob in her friends column (essentially, Jane would have to accept Bob's friend request).

The problem is that you can't seem to update a PFUser unless it's the currently logged in user, as far as I can tell.  So Bob sends a friend request to Jane, and I can store that request in some other table.  Jane accepts the request, and then what?  I can update Jane's friend column when she accepts the request but I can't update Bob's to reflect this change?

The error I get when I try to do this is:

`User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp`

Comment: Write a cloud function and use master key.Or save friends in other table.

Comment: Is it more efficient to have a separate table or to use a relation (since Parse isn't technically a relational db)?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is possible by using a master key, I'd strongly advise against using it in an app.

Try using a join table for the friends relation. It is safer and more efficient, while being pretty straight-forward to implement.

You can even extend the table with additional data to the relation between the two users.

Check the [official guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations-using-join-tables), they have an example similar to your specific case.

Comment: Why do you strongly advise against it in an app?  I'm using some Cloud Code with a master key right now, it's working great.  The thing I don't understand is that Parse bills itself as a noSQL type of database, not relational.  They promote their Relation type as opposed to doing more traditional relational type stuff like join tables.  But you're basically saying that Relations are not to be used at all...is that true?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind would be the App Store review process, imagine how long it would take to fix a possible screw up in a published app that uses the master key and destroys or corrupts records. Regarding the relations, I'd check the Relations guide, they have covered all major cases for all supported relation types. A join table is just one of the relation types they have.